# No wrap of Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, word-wrap, issue-tracking, bootstrap-grid

I've downloaded a ready-made HTML5 website template from w3layouts.com that is under CC3.0 license. Because the used scripts like Bootstrap etc. are all old version I'm updating these and the source code to function. But I'm on a issue that I can't get resolved. I'm new in Bootstrap and it's my first time I'm working with it. I'm tired of coding my own designs. :)

The original/old template is using Bootstrap v3.3.4 and I using now 4.0.0-beta.

As you could see [here in the original](https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/preface-personal-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/) the "My Services" section is all in shape. But in [my updated version](https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1180317/s67kce175hhfe465nk15) the columns wont wrap. I've already tried a lot of things and Googled a lot but found no solution.

Here are the source codes:

- HTML: https:// pastebin.com/NJYmqAk2
- CSS: https:// pastebin.com/AdYUTtFe

(Sorry I had to modify the pastebin links 'cuz I'm not high reputated atm. :))

Comment: Your links are not working for me. I think you should post the html / css code in the post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the version of Bootstrap you're using, is not dividing the columns width in %, and also they are not floating left.

In your HTML, there's a big problem with the **row** wrapped around each column.

```
<div class="row"> <!-- This wraps the column and defeats its purpose -->
 <div class="col-xs-4 wthree_about_right_grid_left">
   <div class="hvr-rectangle-in">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Start by deleting the row, and then you're going to want to make the colums float left and determine it's width in %.

Like this:
[image]

By doing so, you can get it to act like on your template, and ultimately solve your initial problem.

You would benefit far more from using the version of bootstrap that is compatible with your template.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is using flexbox for its grid system, not floats!

Comment: Right, and for that reason my answer is ambivalent. Mixing Bootstrap 3 templates with Bootstrap 4 is not a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, for your solution. I will try it. But if you say it's better to use the Bootstrap 3 version then maybe I should quit updating and use the original version. My thoughts was to bring the template up-to-date. It looks like Bootstrap is more complex as I thought. :) Ah btw. I row'ed the col's 'cuz Bootlint told me it must be.